# Top investors list out of date

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The [top investors in TeX.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/65683/top-investors) result seems to be inaccurate. My current display name with non-Latin and the total of my offered bounties have not been updated.

Comment: You could have mentioned, that you are listed there as the Forgiver. But when I compare the user numbers, they are different. Didn’t you have a user acccount merge last time?

Comment: @Speravir: Some weird things happened after merging my 2 accounts.

Comment: The Data Explorer infrastructure uses past data, not real time. According to the front page, the most recent backup dates June 27. Maybe that's why. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: it should be posted as an answer or i have to delete this question?

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ: I think it's a valid question. `:)` I'll write an answer. `:)`

Comment: Wow. Village sure likes bounties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) infrastructure relies on past data, not real time. In fact, it uses an [anonymized data dump](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/introducing-stack-exchange-data-explorer/) of all creative commons questions and answers from the Stack Exchange family of websites.

We can see the last data update in the front page:

[image: Update]

Once in a while, the data is updated. There are also backups in the XML format available for download in the [ClearBits](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump). I always download the updates and keep a "mirror" of our site in a BitBucket repository:

[[image: BitBucket] TeX.sx data dump](https://bitbucket.org/cereda/tex.sx-data-dump)